# Why is my workflow sending emails for some users, but not others?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email

I have a 2013 workflow I built in SharePoint Designer. It worked fine for me during testing, but when I rolled it out to the end users, only the other administrator and one regular user could get the workflow emails to send.

Everyone now has the same permission level: Edit, but still no success. I know that it's getting stuck at the send email line based on other fields I'm setting directly before that line.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check the workflow output and see if it is cancelling or what the error is that you are getting. Let us know.

Comment: Can you please check by adding logs to workflow history? Also check if workflow gets suspended or not? If Yes, add the error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more it's hard to guess, but it could be that the workflows get suspended due to the users not having write access to the workflow history list. Commonly users with read permission on site level does not have write access to the workflow history list.

This means if your workflow has any log actions it will fail once it get to that action. Also - and this is slightly more illogical - if you havn't unticked the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name" on the workflow setting page - it will fail. Why you might ask? Well that also writes to the workflow history list :)